# Why do I have blank squares for some icons when using font awesome?

Tags: css, fonts, font-awesome

**As you can see in my fiddle, some of the icons from font awesome are not working. Why?**

https://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/80841/

```
<div class="col-md-1 d-flex flex-column justify-content-center align-items-center">
  <i class="fa fa-searchengin"></i>
  <span>SEO</span>
</div>
<div class="col-md-1 d-flex flex-column justify-content-center align-items-center">
  <i class="fa fa-facebook-square"></i>
  <span>Social</span>
</div>
```

Comment: its because you class name are not linked with font class

Comment: Because you have typos. There's no such icon as `fa-searchengin`. You have to specify existing icons from this list: https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/icons/ (from the class names I assumed you are using v4). And also make sure you include the latest CSS.

Comment: I am using 5.1 since there is much more icons I need. https://fontawesome.com/icons?d=gallery&q=searchengin

Comment: Oh, I see, but you are using the v4 classes on the elements.

Comment: Someone else did it, please see the answers below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using an old class. The latest Font Awesome uses the class "fab fa-icon-name" So adding b to your class works.

```
 <div class="col-md-1 d-flex flex-column justify-content-center align-items-center">
  <i class="fab fa-searchengin"></i>
  <span>SEO</span>
</div>
<div class="col-md-1 d-flex flex-column justify-content-center align-items-center">
  <i class="fab fa-facebook-square"></i>
  <span>Social</span>
</div>
```

JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1n74q20u/

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="col-md-1 d-flex flex-column justify-content-center align-items-center">
  <i class="fab fa-searchengin"></i>
<span>SEO</span>
</div>
<div class="col-md-1 d-flex flex-column justify-content-center align-items-center">
  <i class="fab fa-facebook-square"></i>
 <span>Social</span>
</div>
```

Check the font awesome page and ensure the first class matches what you are using. On that jsfiddle, I've changed fa to fab and they all work.